# Activating appropriate worksheet and renaming it

Tags: vba, excel

I have been adding worksheets from different workbooks into one for ease, however, when I copy and paste the code into the new model in the new workbook, the code keeps on showing me an error, despite it working in the old workbook. 
In the code below, how can I activate worksheet "Question3" and have "Set myRange = question3.Range("A3") not give me an error, like it wasn't before I copied and pasted it into my new workbook. 
Thank You.

```
 Sub Main()
 Dim gender As String
   Call GetResponse(gender)
   Call NameGenderRange(gender)
   Call FormatOutputRange(gender)
   Call EnterOutput(gender)
 End Sub

Sub GetResponse(gender As String)

  Dim response As Variant '<-- since the user can respond in alphabets or     anything else
  Dim ErrorCheck As Boolean

    Do
      response = InputBox("please enter 1 for boys, or 2 for girls") '<--prompting user for input
      If IsNumeric(response) = False Then
        ErrorCheck = True  '<-- ensuring the input value is an integer
        MsgBox ("Please enter a valid entry") '<-- ensuring user inputs  only 1 or 2
      ElseIf response = 1 Then '<-- if logic to differentiate between the gender averages
        gender = "boys"
      ElseIf response = 2 Then
        gender = "girls"
      Else
        ErrorCheck = False
      End If  
    Loop Until response = 1 Or response = 2 '<-- continously prompting the user to enter a correct value
End Sub

Sub NameGenderRange(gender As String)
Dim myRange As Range '<-- selecting the appropriate column to calculate   the average
Dim question3 As Worksheet

  If gender = "boys" Then
    Set myRange = question3.Range("A3") '<-- selecting the column contaning  data for boys
  Else
    Set myRange = question3.Range("B3") '<-- slecting the column contaning data for girls
  End If
  With myRange
    Range(.Offset(1, 0), .End(xlDown)).Name = "average" '<--selecting the whole column and calling it "average"
  End With
End Sub

Sub FormatOutputRange(gender As String)
  With question3.Range("D9:E9") '<-- selecting the rows to display the "average"
    With .Font
      .Size = 12
      .Underline = True '<-- altering the font
      .Bold = True
      .TintAndShade = 0
      If gender = "boys" Then '<-- If logic to differentiate by colour
        .ColorIndex = 5
      Else
        .ColorIndex = 3
      End If
    End With
  End With
End Sub

 Sub EnterOutput(gender As String)
   question3.Range("D9").Value = "The average for " & gender & " is" '<-- naming the row to display the average
   question3.Range("E9").Formula = "=Average(average)" '<-- displaying the   average in cell E9
 End Sub
```

Comment: You dim `question3` but you never actually set it to a worksheet.  Immediately after the Dim line, put in a Set line: `Set question3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Question3")`

Comment: Also, don't you need to make `gender` something when calling your subs? What do they do when `gender` is `nothing`? I'm surprised this doesn't throw an error when trying to run `Main()`.

Comment: Thanks @tigeravatar it worked perfectly, I had forgotten to set it to the active workbook!

Comment: @BruceWayne I did Dim gender As String, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yeah, but then when `GetResponse(sender)` is called, what does the function use as `sender`? What value is passed there? (I'm kinda new to UDF, so am wondering how you can pass a (seemingly) nonexistant variable? Am I missing something?)

Comment: @BruceWayne - `Dim gender As String` creates a string variable, and sets it to the default value of an empty string (i.e. `""`).  As it is never assigned another value before the statement `Call GetResponse(gender)`, that subroutine receives a reference to a string variable which has a value of `""`.  The subroutine then changes the value of the variable referred to and so, when the `Call NameGenderRange(gender)` statement is executed, the `NameGenderRange` subroutine is passed a reference to a string variable which now contains either `"boys"` or `"girls"`.